# java.io.IOException: Invalid header signature; read 1688935826934608, expected -2226271756974174256

Tags: java

I am reading data from excel file. There is not errors, but I am getting exception

```
 like Invalid header signature; read 1688935826934608, expected -2226271756974174256
 is at an error in code a=or in excel file
```

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell; 
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook; 
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
public class Exexel1
{
    public static void main( String [] args ) 
    { 
     try
      {  
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/sample.xlsx"));
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input );
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0); 
        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
        while( rows.hasNext() ) 
        {
            HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
            System.out.println("\n");
            Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
            while( cells.hasNext() ) 
            {
                HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
                if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC==cell.getCellType()) 
                    System.out.print( cell.getNumericCellValue()+" " );
                else if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING==cell.getCellType())
                    System.out.print( cell.getStringCellValue()+" " ); 
                else if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN==cell.getCellType())
                    System.out.print( cell.getBooleanCellValue()+" " );
                else if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK==cell.getCellType()) 
                    System.out.print( "BLANK " ); 
                else System.out.print("Unknown cell type");
            }
        }
    } catch ( IOException ex )
       {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Please show us some more Stacktrace information. And at best create a running example which reproduces your problem.

Comment: You understand that an Excel file is a JAR file, right?  So the JAR needs to be "opened" to access individual members inside it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053350/invalid-header-signature-opening-xls-with-apache-poi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846398/use-poi-to-parse-excel-but-got-exception-invalid-header-signature

Comment: @HotLicks An Excel file is not a JAR file. What are you talking about?

Comment: @EJP - Well, an xlsx file starts with `50 4b 03 04 14 00 06 00 08 00 00 00 21 00 df cf   PK............!.BI` -- That sure looks like a JAR file to me.  And 7-Zip thinks it a JAR file, with 3 directories and an XML file.  All told, about 20 files.

Comment: So it's a ZIP file. A JAR file is also a ZIP file but it also contains a manifest.